# Changing the cursor in Lightbox

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Lightbox on my site and it is great. However, when I hover over a thumbnail the cursor changes to a little hand, which is what I want. But when I click on an image and it goes big, the cursor is then a pointer. Can I change it so it stays as a hand when I hover over the big image?

I cannot find anything in the lightbox.css

Comment: using css `#thumbnail { cursor: pointer; }` should be enough.

Comment: Use Chrome, right click and "inspect element", check out where the cursor style is being applied, then go change it... or work out how to do the equivalent in your favourite obsolete browser instead

Comment: You want css - { cursor: pointer; }

Comment: share url so we can check it live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following in `lightbox.css` OR create **new** css file and include it **after** `lightbox.css` OR add it to your **custom css** file which you are including after `lightbox.css`

`.lb-nav { cursor: pointer; }`

Comment: They're exactly the same thing :p

Comment: I just gave possible solutions that came into my mind. Better way is to inspect his link live.

Comment: No, I mean with and without hover are exactly the same for cursor.  It *has* to be on hover, but doesn't require it.